# Python: match and replace all whitespaces at the beginning of each line

Tags: python, regex

I need to convert text like this:

```
' 1 white space before string'
'  2 white spaces before string'
'   3 white spaces before string'
```

Into a:

```
'&nbsp;1 white space before string'
'&nbsp;&nbsp;2 white spaces before string'
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 white spaces before string'
```

Whitespaces between words and at the end of the line should not be matched, only at the beginning. Also, no need to match tabs. Big thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with a callback that performs the actual replacement:

```
import re

list_of_strings = [...]

p = re.compile('^ +')
for i, l in enumerate(list_of_strings): 
    list_of_strings[i] = p.sub(lambda x: x.group().replace(' ', '&nbsp;'), l)
```

```
print(list_of_strings)
['&nbsp;1 white space before string',
 '&nbsp;&nbsp;2 white spaces before string',
 '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 white spaces before string'
]
```

The pattern used here is `'^ +'` and will search for, and replace whitespaces as long as they're at the start of your string.

Comment: Downvoter? Can you let me know whether this doesn't work, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you know it's just spaces as leading whitespace, you could do something like this:

```
l = '&nbsp;' * (len(l) - len(l.lstrip())) + l.lstrip()
```

Not the most efficient though.  This would be a bit better:

```
stripped = l.strip()
l = '&nbsp;' * (len(l) - len(stripped)) + stripped
print(l)
```

It's one way to do it without the `re` overhead.

For example:

```
lines = [
    ' 1 white space before string',
    '  2 white spaces before string',
    '   3 white spaces before string',
]

for l in lines:
    stripped = l.strip()
    l = '&nbsp;' * (len(l) - len(stripped)) + stripped
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
&nbsp;1 white space before string
&nbsp;&nbsp;2 white spaces before string
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 white spaces before string
```

Comment: Nice idea) but I do not exclude that some whitespaces can be at the end of some line also

Comment: @MaxCore Whitespace at the end of the line is fine, `lstrip` will only trim from the left side/leading edge of the string.  My qualification of "*If you know it's just spaces as leading whitespace*" was trying to point out that it will also strip and replace non-space whitespace characters (tabs, newlines, etc).